# How do I get my code from going into an infinte loop?

Tags: c, loops, infinite

I am rewriting the Guessing Game code from 'C Programming for Absoulute Beginners' to verify that the user has entered in a digit, using the isdigit() function.

The rest of the code works, in terms of error checking; but the moment that the user enters in a non-digit, the code goes into an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NO 2
#define YES 1

main()

{
    int guessGame;    
    guessGame = 0;

    int iRandomNum = 0;
    int iResponse = 0;

    printf("\n\nWould you like to play \"The Guessing Game\"?\n\n"); 
    printf("\nType '1' for Yes or '2' for No!\n\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &guessGame);

    do{
        if(guessGame == YES){
            iRandomNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

            printf("\nGuess a number between 1 and 10:\n\n ");
            scanf("%d", &iResponse);

            if(!isdigit(iResponse)){
                printf("\nThank you\n");
                printf("\nYou entered %d\n", iResponse);
                if(iResponse == iRandomNum){
                    printf("\nYou guessed right\n");
                    printf("\nThe correct guess is %d!\n", iRandomNum);
                    printf("\nDo you wish to continue? \n");
                    printf("\nType '1' for Yes or '2' for No!\n\n");
                    scanf("%d", &guessGame);

               } else {
                    printf("\n\nSorry, you guessed wrong\n");
                    printf("\nThe correct guess was %d!\n", iRandomNum);
                    printf("\n\nDo you wish to continue? \n");
                    printf("\nType '1' for Yes or '2' for No!\n\n");
                    scanf("%d", &guessGame);

                }
            }
            else {
                printf("\nYou did not enter a digit\n");
                printf("\n\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 10:\n\n");
                scanf("%d", &iResponse);
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("\nThe window will now close. Try again later!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }while(guessGame != NO);
}
```

Comment: What debugger have you used to step through this?

Comment: shouldn't `if(!isdigit(iResponse))` be `if(isdigit(iResponse))`? if indeed it's checking for a digit..

Comment: @Ben I have not used any debugger to step though the code yet. I am using DevC++ to write and compile it. But, unfortunately the debugger is not working atm and I've not got around to searching for the solution to get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @David.C.Rankin, is it really that simple?

Comment: @downshift I thought the same thing too. However, the corresponding code block is skipped, when I use if(isdigit(iResponse)) and that is not what I desire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code goes into infinite loop as scanf() is unable to read an integer. The character you entered remains in the keyboard buffer.No more reading of integers is possible as long as the character is present in the buffer. scanf() simply returns the number of items read as 0 each time. Hence,the program does not wait for the user to enter data and infinite loop results.

scanf() returns number of items successfully read. So,you can simply check for the return value of scanf(), if its 1 then scanf() has correctly read an integer.

```
   check = scanf("%d", &iResponse);

   if(check == 1){
        printf("\nThank you\n");
        printf("\nYou entered %d\n", iResponse);
```

and flush the buffer if wrong input is entered

```
        else {
            while (getchar() != '\n');  //flush the buffer
            printf("\nYou did not enter a digit\n");
            printf("\n\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 10:\n\n");
            //scanf("%d", &iResponse);
        }
```

no need to ask for input here, while loop will continue and prompt for input in the beginning

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Hardik. It certainly deals with my infinite loop issue, which is very much appreciated. However, with regards to your comment that scanf() is unable to read an integer, can you please enlighten me on why this issue did not happen in the outer loop: scanf(" %d", &guessGame);? Additionally, is there a way to accomplish the same task, using the isdigit() function?

Comment: You have initialized guessGame = 0; so for the outer loop , when invalid input is entered scanf() will not be able to read . Hence guessGame is still 0 . Then Inside the loop, check is present if(guessGame == YES) from where it will come out of the loop and the execution stops.

Comment: Use a debugger, you can understand/solve all your problems using it.

Comment: Thanks alot for the clarification @Hardik. It's very much appreciated. My intention is to use a debugger. However, my fresh install of DevC++ does not seem to have it enabled. Any ideas on how to set it up?

Answer (score 2):

Trying taking the input in the form of string .. also u will have to compare the input in the form 'number' :)